# TypeScript function, which returns value of the same type as it's input

Tags: typescript, generics, return-type

Please, consider the following example:

```typescript
interface HashMap<Type> {
  [key: string]: Type;
}

type StringVariations = (string | string[] | HashMap<string>);

function foo<Type extends StringVariations>(input: Type): Type {
    if ('string' === typeof input) {
        return 'foo';
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```

I have a function, which accepts various types as it's input. However, it always returns the same type as it receives.

What would be a correct way to define this in TypeScript?

The above example gives me an error: `Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'Type'.`

Comment: Tangential, but you most likely want `<Type extends StringVariations>` if you expect this function to only be called with string variations.  `<Type = StringVariations>` means that `Type` can be anything, but defaults to `StringVariations`, which might not be what you want.

Comment: @Retsam thanks, that was exactly my intention! I just didn't know the right syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript will not narrow the generic type even if you do type checking. Such behavior is simply not implemented. Since no narrowing is done, any value that you assign to `T` must be valid for any conceivable `T`. Also keep in mind that given your type constaint derived types are possible, so `T` could be a string literal type, and then your  check is not enough to ensure the correct return type :

```
foo<'bar' >('bar') // Returns 'foo' but 'bar' is expected
```

If you want to go ahead with this you will to use a type assertion

```
function foo<Type = StringVariations>(input: Type): Type {
    if ('string' === typeof input) {
        return 'foo' as any;
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```