# TypeScript: Generic function which returns the same type as parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, types, casting

Consider this (which doesn't compile):

```
function roundTo<T = number | null | undefined>(
  num: T,
  decimals: number,
): T {
  if (num === null || num === undefined) return num;

  const factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return (Math.round(num * factor) / factor);
}
```

I would like to return the same type that's passed in to the `roundTo()` function.

For example:

```
const num1: number | null = 1.123456;
roundTo(num1, 1) // return type number | null

const num2: number = 1.123456;
roundTo(num2, 1) // return type number

const num3 = null;
roundTo(num3, 1) // return type null
```

The return type of `roundTo` is known at compile time, so the desire is to be able to carry the type forward from there based on the type passed in the first parameter.

I can make this compile by casting the return type `as any`, but that would break type safety. I can also make this compile by using `extends` instead of `=` and casing the return type `as T`, but it has the undesired behavior of returning `any` when `null` or `undefined` is passed in.

How can I get TypeScript to exhibit the desired behavior?

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51195834/188740
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57529925/188740

Comment: [Unable to reproduce the undesired behavior](https://tsplay.dev/WKqnDN).

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code, and I can't tell which of them are the core of your question and which are incidental.  I will describe them here and then you can decide which ones you want to fix in the question itself so that they are not distractions from your actual issue.

Comment: • You are using a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) (`T = ...`) when you should be using a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) (`T extends ...`); right now I can call `roundTo(new Date(), 1)` because `T` is not constrained at all.  Do you intend to support such a call?  And given that `T` will always be inferred from the `num` input, there is nothing for the default to do.

Comment: • You do not want to return the same type `T` as the input.  TypeScript has numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) so `T` might be narrower than `number`.  If you do constrain `T extends number | null | undefined`, then `roundTo(0.01, 1)` will purportedly return a value of type `0.01`, which is the type of the input.  But you're actually returning `0`.  If you want to return `number` then you can't return `T`, you need some conditional type like `T extends number ? number : T`

Comment: • The compiler cannot narrow the type parameter `T` inside the function body. There are a number of open requests to deal with this, like [ms/TS#33014](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  For now that means `if (num === null || num === undefined)` has no effect on `T` so the compiler can never be sure if your output is of type `T` unless you return `num` itself. And it especially can't be sure if you're returning a conditional type. Type assertions (what you call "casting") or the like will be needed. The other question you link does that; why does `as any` not work for you?

Comment: • Your `roundTo` function requires two inputs but your examples show it being called with only one.  Why?

Comment: • "I can make this compile by using `extends` instead of `=` and casing the return type as `T`, but it has the undesired behavior of returning `any` when `null` or `undefined` is passed in." This shouldn't be happening and you haven't demonstrated it with a [mre].  Maybe you don't have `--strictNullChecks` enabled?  But if so then you probably wouldn't care about passing `null` and `undefined` around since they have no type-level significance.  If you turn on `--strictNullChecks` does this problem go away?  Is that part of your question?

Comment: Okay, I'm done.  If you could please clean the question up so that only one or maybe two of those bullet points still apply then I'd be happy to come back and provide an answer with an explanation.  Otherwise there's just too much going on here, at least for me.  Good luck!

Comment: @catgirlkelly Thanks for the gist. It works quite well except for one problem that jcalz pointed out (literal types).

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the input. You make a lot of good points. I've collected your thoughts together with catgirlkelly's example and I think I came up with a workable solution. I'll post it in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to @jcalz.

Use an overload signature to set a conditional return type of `T extends number ? number : T`. Then the implementation can relax the type inference.

```
// Overload signature
export function roundTo<T extends number | null | undefined>(
  num: T,
  decimals: number,
): T extends number ? number : T;

// Implementation
export function roundTo(
  num: number | null | undefined,
  decimals: number,
) {
  if (num === null || num === undefined) return num;
  const factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return Math.round(num * factor) / factor;
}
```

Examples:

```
roundTo(undefined, 2) // Returns type `undefined`
roundTo(null, 2) // Returns type `null`
roundTo(1.234 as number | undefined, 2) // Returns type `number | undefined`
roundTo(1.234 as number | null, 2) // Returns type `number | null`
roundTo(1.234, 2) // Returns type `number`
```

Comment: @jcalz Please let me know if there's a way to improve this

Comment: I'd probably write [this](https://tsplay.dev/w65g6W) ... you want the return type to *always* be `T extends number ? number : T`.  Since the compiler can't narrow type parameters via control flow analysis and has no idea if the return type will be assignable to the conditional type, as per https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912, I'd give up on trying to strongly type the implementation and instead loosen it with a single call signature overload.  It's equivalent to [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPZLZN), but I prefer the overload since otherwise you're writing lots of assertions.

Comment: @jcalz Brilliant, I updated the answer to reflect your changes. Thanks for walking me through this!

Answer (score 2):

It should be `T extends ...`, not `T = ...`. The latter form is "default value for T", and it is not inferred but rather always taken as declared, basically killing entire idea.

```
  function roundTo<T extends number | null | undefined>(num: T, decimals: number): T {
    if (num == null) return num;
    const factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return (Math.round((num as number) * factor) / factor) as T;
  }

  function test(x: number, y: null, z: undefined, t?: number, u?: null) {
    let x1 = roundTo(x, 2); // -> number
    let x2 = roundTo(y, 2); // -> null
    let x3 = roundTo(z, 2); // -> undefined
    let x4 = roundTo(t, 2); // -> number | undefined
    let x5 = roundTo(u, 2); // -> null | undefined
  }
```

Actually, you can get rid of one type coersion `num as number` but probably not the other (at least not an easy way)

```
  function roundTo<T extends number | null | undefined>(num: T, decimals: number): T {
    if (typeof num === 'number') {
      // here typescript knows, that num is specific subtype of T - number
      // but doesn't extend this to the T itself
      const factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
      return Math.round(num * factor) / factor as T;
    }
    return num;
  }
```

If you *really* want to force typescript infer actual type of T inside the function, probably conditional typings are the way, but imho it's overkill.

One more point from @Johnny Oshika - to avoid unwanted narrowing of number types overloads can be used:

```
  function roundTo(num: number, decimals: number): number;
  function roundTo<T extends number | null | undefined>(num: T, decimals: number): T;
  function roundTo<T extends number | null | undefined>(num: T, decimals: number): T {
   // function body
  }
```

Comment: As @jcalz mentioned in one of the comments, returning `T` has the undesirable effect of returning a literal type if something like this is passed in: `roundTo(1.234, 2)`. TypeScript will report that type `1.234` is being returned when in fact `1.23` is being returned.

Comment: Oh, I guess then overloads will do the thing

Comment: I like your type guard to to get rid of a type coersion. I borrowed it in my answer below.